# Position road labels above lines with cartocss in Tilemill

Tags: mapbox, tilemill, cartography

I am styling a map in Tilemill and am attempting to place all my road labels above the road lines.

By setting (text-dy: 10;) the label should be placed above the line.  Unfortunately sometimes the label is placed 10px below the line instead.  How would I set up my stylesheet so the label is explicitly above the line?

The following is an example of one of my cartocss rules for roads that I am having an issue with.

```
#mainroad_label[type='secondary'][zoom>13] {
text-name:'[name]';
text-face-name:@metPlusMedCaps;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-placement:line;
text-dy: 10;
text-min-distance:60;
text-size:14;
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Tilemills label placement can be awfully confusing sometimes.